# install4j 7.0.6: Cancel installation from "Replacement script for language code"

Tags: java, install4j

We have a use case which requires cancelling the installation from the "Replacement script for language code" - General Customization Option of the Installer.

Is there a way to achieve this either programatically or by configuration?

Comment: Can you post what you have already tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can call

```
context.finish(1);
```

in that script.